# How to Add Prefix in XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml like this

```
<eo-gateway>
<interface-code>AAA</interface-code>
<supplier-code>XXX</supplier-code>
<authors>
<author type="first">
<forename>John</forename>
<surname>Smith</surname>
</author>
</authors>
</eo-gateway>
```

I need to arrive to this kind of xml adding prefix "art" in each tag.

```
<art:eo-gateway>
<art:interface-code>AAA</art:interface-code>
<art:supplier-code>XXX</art:supplier-code>
<art:authors>
<art:author type="first">
<art:forename>John</art:forename>
<art:surname>Smith</art:surname>
</art:author>
</art:authors>
</art:eo-gateway>
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You target XML is invalid. `art:` would be an namespace prefix and need to be defined - `<art:eo-gateway xmlns:art="urn:art">`. But this has the same meaning like `<eo-gateway xmlns="urn:art">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the correct way to solve this using xml.etree that eliminates having extra tags like html and body tags from BeautifulSoup.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

xml_content = """<eo-gateway>
    <interface-code>AAA</interface-code>
    <supplier-code>XXX</supplier-code>
    <authors>
    <author type="first">
    <forename>John</forename>
    <surname>Smith</surname>
    </author>
    </authors>
    </eo-gateway>"""

document_root = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring(xml_content))
for element in document_root.getiterator():
    element.tag = "art:" + element.tag
print etree.tostring(document_root.getroot())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use beautifulsoup :http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<eo-gateway>
<interface-code>AAA</interface-code>
<supplier-code>XXX</supplier-code>
<authors>
<author type="first">
<forename>John</forename>
<surname>Smith</surname>
</author>
</authors>
</eo-gateway>''')

for i in soup.find_all():
    i.name = 'art:' + i.name
```

And if you don't want some tags you could do this:

```
except_these = ['art:body', 'art:html']

for i in soup.find_all():
    name = i.name
    if name not in except_these:
        i.name = 'art:' + i.name
print soup
```

Output:

```
<art:body>
<art:eo-gateway>
<art:interface-code>AAA</art:interface-code>
<art:supplier-code>XXX</art:supplier-code>
<art:authors>
<art:author type="first">
<art:forename>John</art:forename>
<art:surname>Smith</art:surname>
</art:author>
</art:authors>
</art:eo-gateway>
</art:body>
```

Or you could even check whether it already has 'art:' in front of it:

```
if !name.startswith('art:'):
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. This works however <art:html><art:body></art:body></art:html> are auto generated and added to the tags.  How exclude them?  Thanks

Comment: I've tried above resolution but still got <art:html><art:body></art:body></art:html>.  I'm also confused with the output you've provided since there is still <art:body> even if it is excluded under except_these.

Comment: Do you want to delete these tags?